# What is max size of data stored in a parameter of Procedure in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tried calling following procedure

```
call `CreateNewMemoOut_Procedure`('25076','25076===0===593===2017-02-06===2017-02-06===2017-02-06===0=========0===0===0===46======0===232===83.83000000000013==================0===10249.56===20===0===0===162430.45===162410.45===162410.45===0===1===US Dollar (USD)===US$===1===0===|','25076===Diamonds=========181248======18===BR===H===VS1===0.34===GIA===2100===-25===1===1490===1575===535.5===1===Ct======2100===0.34===1===7226836609===STAR RAYS===0===0===0000-00-00===2100===-25===0===0===0======0===1===1490===1575===535.5===0===227720===BEJA===0===N===0===0======|25076===Diamonds=========114153======92===BR===H===VS2===0.34===GIA===2000===-10===1===1870===1800===612===2===Ct======2000===0.34===1===2176298357===STAR RAYS===0===0===0000-00-00===2000===-10===0===0===0======0===1===1870===1800===612===0===227721===BIHA===0===N===0===0======|25076===Diamonds=========181483======19===BR===G===VS1===0.32===GIA===2200===-25===1===1520===0===0======0===1===2432===2487.33=======0===1===2210===2380===1094.8===0===227938===CCBA===0===N===0===0======|25=0===0000-00-00===3600===-13.73===0===0===0======0===1===2780===3105.72===1739.2===0===228096======0======0===0======|','','developer','232','0','0','paris gh','@status','@message','@memo')
```

The third parameter i.e. a string is of Long Text Type.

But it only shows around 65 k words rather it should show more than that as this string contains 3 times that data. The rest data is stripped out.

MySql version used here: 
5.6.33-log